# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I try to access a route at logout, but I get the error from title.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/logout', function() {

    if( cas()->isAuthenticated() ) {
        session()->flush();
        cas()->logout();
    } else {
        session()->flush(); // dd here works
        return redirect('/');
    }
});

Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'login',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
]);
```

**HomeController**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    dd(123); // I can't get here
}
```

Comment: can you use dump or var_dump instead of dd? Check how many time is 'session()->flush()' run..

Comment: Just one in /logout , but in 127.0.0.1 it's a loop.

Comment: so your index is looping? Are you sure it about other codes?

Answer (score 0):

If `cas()` is using sessions for authentication don't flush the session before calling `cas()->logout()`.

Otherwise the problem is likely in Middlewares which interfere. You may need to remove the default Laravel `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware from `App\Http\Kernel.php @ web` group.

---

As sidenote: when logging something out, I recommend not to destroy the whole session but only the keys which are related to the subject which is being logged out by using `session()->forget('key')`. Destroying the entire session may cause unexpected interference from other sides.

Hope this answers helps you.

Comment: I removed RedirectIfAuthenticated, still the same. If I comment Route with '/' , I get redirected to cas login page.